# Surround all characters

Tags: python, string

I want to "surround" all characters in a string with pipes:

```
'abc'   => '|a|b|c|'
'abcde' => '|a|b|c|d|e|'
'x'     => '|x|'
''      => '|'
```

What's a good way to do it, preferably as a one-line expression? Here's a way with a loop:

```
s = 'abcde'

t = '|'
for c in s:
    t += c + '|'

print(t)    # |a|b|c|d|e|
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out we can create something from nothing:

```
s.replace('', '|')
```

Demo:

```
for s in 'abc', 'abcde', 'x', '':
    print(s.replace('', '|'))
```

Output:

```
|a|b|c|
|a|b|c|d|e|
|x|
|
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `'|'.join()`, just need to add two null strings.

```
def f(s):
    return '|'.join(['', *s, ''])
```

```
>>> f('abc')
'|a|b|c|'
>>> f('abcde')
'|a|b|c|d|e|'
>>> f('x')
'|x|'
>>> f('')
'|'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using string method `join` as follows:

```
''.join('|'+e for e in s) + '|'
```

It works on all of your examples.